# Is there anyway I could use nullable datetime property to get the year?

Tags: linq, datetime

I am trying to perform the following linq to entities query-

```
var data = DataContext.Employee.Where(e=>e.Date.Year>1986).ToList();
```

Now the problem is that `Date` field is a nullable DateTime field and I can't access Year property and on the database side I can't change legacy code! ....anyways is there anyway possible to use the year property?

Comment: May I just add that using year to determine age smells fishy...

Comment: ya..its just a contrived example..updated it to avoid confusion..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = DataContext.Employee
    .Where(e=>e.Date.HasValue && e.Date.Value.Year>1986).ToList();
```

Note that this will not include Employees without a date in the list.

Comment: out of curiosity, will LINQ2SQL see this and translate it to SQL or pull down all records and perform the lambda in code?